# Move only some x axis labels down in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

See this plot:

```r
tibble(x = 0:10, y = rnorm(11)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0,10,2)/10, seq(2,10,1)))
```

[image]

The labels in the beginning of the axis are very crowded. Is there a way to push down only **some** labels (e.g. those of `c(0.2, 0.6, 0.8)`) so that all labels would be readable? Bonus: add a vertical line from ticks to those labels which have been pushed down (in other words make the tick longer).

I know I can use `vjust = -5` as in `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -5))` but that would push down all labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it the hard way, if you really want those long ticks

```r
tibble(x = 0:10, y = rnorm(11)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(2, 10, 4)/10, color = "white", size = 0.5) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0,10,4)/10, seq(2,10,1))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = c(-2, 2)) +
  annotate("text", label = format(seq(2, 10, 4)/10, nsmall = 1),
           x = seq(2, 10, 4)/10, y = -2.4,
           size = 3) +
  annotate("segment", x = seq(2, 10, 4)/10, xend = seq(2, 10, 4)/10,
           y = -2.33, yend = -2.2, size = 0.2) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple method that pushes down the axis text by adding a new line character `\n` before the label in the vector `x_ticks`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
x_ticks <- c(seq(0,10,2)/10, seq(2,10,1))

tibble(x = 0:10, y = rnorm(11)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_ticks, 
                     labels = ifelse(x_ticks %in% c(0.2, 0.6, 0.8), 
                                     paste0("\n", x_ticks), x_ticks))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>